# Returning custom message in an http exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

This is my ExceptionHandler class

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NotFoundException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1964839652066902559L;

    public NotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

In my service I have

```
@Service
public class myService {
 public String getName() throws NotFoundException{
            logger.error("Name not found");
            throw new NotFoundException("Name not found");
        }
}
```

The response I get is:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1486967853916,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "exception": "com.exceptions.NotFoundException",
  "message": "Not Found",
  "path": "/names"
}
```

I just want my message to be passed from the service and returned in the exception. But this is not happening can anyone tell how do I do it.

Comment: `public class myService throws NotFoundException` Are you able to compile this? And how are you even getting a response?

Comment: yes. I haven't put the controller code. My controller this service

Comment: Thanks for correcting the question. And FYI: I did not vote down your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use combination of @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler, may this will help you.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalValidationResponse extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<?> handleEntityNotFoundException(NotFoundException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new ValidationError(ex.getMessage()));

        }
}
```

Entity of ValidationError

```
public class ValidationError {

    //@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();

    private String errorMessage;

    public ValidationError() {
        super();
    }

    public ValidationError(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public ValidationError(Map<String, String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(Map<String, String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I explicitly throw this exception from my service

Comment: as you already throwed in service - throw new NotFoundException("Name not found");

Comment: {
  "timestamp": 1486971408978,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "javassist.NotFoundException",
  "message": "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javassist.NotFoundException: vfcd",
  "path": "/names"
}

Comment: I am getting status code as 500. I need it to be 404

Comment: 500 means thats a internal server error. return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new ValidationError(ex.getMessage()));

Comment: return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new ValidationError(ex.getMessage())); I have this

Comment: set message on ValidationError entity and try to return it.